# How to select or filter Google Sheets data via Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Google Apps script seems powerful on the surface, but it seems to be lacking a LINQ-style easy select/filter mechanism.

E.g. I am trying to gain some insights into my spending habits, so I created a spreadsheet with transactions for the last 3 months. Let's say the columns are date, category, merchant and amount.

I can seem to select ranges by hardcoding cell values, but I cannot select all transactions for only the month of May, and then sum them up by category. Instead I have to select *all* the data in the sheet using getDataRange and then loop over it, which seems clumsy.

```
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
```

After summing spend by category, I would like to move on to answering more complicated questions like: Which restaurant have I spent the most money at? Which cuisine do I only visit 1 restaurant for? Do I go to bars more frequently on weekends or weekdays?

The logic to solve questions like these, or even simple ones like sum by category, requires strong selection/query language. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: There's a inbuilt query formula. There's also the explore feature. [tag:google-query-language] might help you to programmatically do this,if needed.